# Incorrect conversion from hex to int in C#

Tags: c#, int, hex

What can be the reason for the problem? My method returns incorrect int values. When I give it hex value of AB or DC or something similar it returns int = 0 but when I give it a hex = 22 it returns me int = 22. (though int should be 34 in this case).

```
public int StatusBit(int Xx, int Rr)  {
        int Number;
        int.TryParse(GetX(Xx,Rr), out Number);
            return Number;
    }
```

I tried to use Number = Convert.ToInt32(GetX(Xx,Rr)); but it gives same result but null instead of 0 for anything that includes letters.

Comment: What is `GetX`? int.Parse / int.TryParse only understands base10, not base16.

Comment: Rowland: It returns a string, I'd guess. But I'd say it's not terribly important here, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Convert.ToInt32(string, int)` instead. That way you can give a base the number should be interpreted in. E.g.

```
return Convert.ToInt32(GetX(Xx, Rr), 16);
```

(You also don't check the return value of `TryParse` which would give a hint that the parse failed.)

If you expect both decimal and hexadecimal numbers you need to branch according to how the number looks and use either base 10 or base 16. E.g. if your hexadeximal numbers always start with `0x` you could use something along the following lines:

```
string temp = GetX(Xx, Rr);
return Convert.ToInt32(temp, temp.StartsWith("0x") ? 16 : 10);
```

But that would depend on how (if at all) you would distinguish the two. If everything is hexadecimal then there is no such need, of course.

Comment: With Convert.ToInt32 you cannot handle failures (only as exceptions which isnt clean). This is why TryParse is better.

Answer (score 4):

Use `NumberStyles.HexNumber`:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string text = "22";
        int value;
        int.TryParse(text, NumberStyles.HexNumber, 
                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out value);
        Console.WriteLine(value); // Prints 34
    }
}
```

Do you really want to silently return 0 if the value can't be parsed, by the way? If not, use the return value of `int.TryParse` to determine whether the parsing succeeded or not. (That's the reason it's returning 0 for "AB" in your original code.)

Comment: Cute, didn't know about that one. Is there a preference for one method over the other here (apart from the semantics regarding unparseable input which obviously depends on what one needs)?

Comment: @Joey: Personally I prefer using `TryParse` as it provides more control.

Comment: `if(!int.TryParse("22", NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out int hexNumber)) return 0;` int named hexNumber is now available for use, small and deadly when using out int rather than just out, out int creates the variable and outs to it whereas out references an int and outs to it.

Comment: @MaDude: Yes, I'm very aware of `out` parameter support in C# 7, but I'm not going over all my posts that are over 5 years old to edit them all...

Comment: @JonSkeet Was pointing out for other users who arrive here m8, calm down

Answer (score 1):

`int.TryParse` parses a base 10 integer.

Use `Convert.ToUInt32(hex, 16)` instead

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution;

```
kTemp = int.Parse(xcc, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

above *kTemp* is an integer, and *xcc* is a string. 
*xcc* can be anything like; FE, 10BA, FE0912... that is to say; *xcc* is a string of hex characters in any length.
beware; I dont get the *0x* prefix with my hex strings.